# Bootstrap 3: is role navigation necessary?

Tags: html, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is role navigation necessary in Bootstrap 3?

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
...
</div>
</header>
```

This code have HTML5 validation error - no navigation on role attribute. I can omit role navigation and visually - and no changes happens.

Answer (score 0):

The role attribute is to help assistive technology (such as screen readers) present the page to users. You should not omit it.

The error is in using `<header>` for a navigation section instead of [`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element).

(If there is non-navigation content there as well, then the `<nav>` element (with the role attribute) should be inside the `<header>` but only around those elements).